# How do we want to handle the old questions that got obsoleted by the IOTA Chrysalis update?

Tags: discussion

Due to the Chrysalis network update on Mainnet that happened April 28, 2020, many old questions/answers (particularly those around trinary encoding and Winternitz signatures, but also low-level questions about message format internals) became obsolete and only of historic interest.

How should we go treat them?

I noticed that [Antonio Nardella](https://iota.stackexchange.com/users/3560/antonio-nardella)
started [posting](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2293#2649) [answers](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2409#2648) to those questions. I myself am tagging all those questions with the [legacy-protocol](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legacy-protocol) tag when I stumble upon them.

But I believe we could need more coordination here. And maybe some tooling (if it exists) like a displayed banner to make it more obvious to newbies that those questions are not relevant to the IOTA network deployed today and only of historic interest.

**EDIT** As pointed out in [the answer below](https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/134), we could create a custom post notice for that. Any suggestions for the wording are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello and thanks for pointing that out!

I see that it looks like StackExchange has the option to add banners to questions
[image]

Is it possible that such option is available in the moderation tools?

Comment: That is a good idea. Moderators can toggle "post notices" for questions, but the notice itself would have to be created by StackExchange as a custom post notice for our site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191981/what-about-site-specific-post-notices