# Custom post notice for IOTA legacy questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Referring to [How do we want to handle the old questions that got obsoleted by the IOTA Chrysalis update?](https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191984/, we'd like to have a custom post notice on the IOTA site:

> This question is about an obsolete legacy IOTA protocol that is no longer used on the IOTA mainnet. Its content is preserved mainly for historic interest. If you are interested in how this is handled in the current IOTA mainnet, search for similar questions or ask a new one.

I am aware that only we mods can add those notice, but others can tag questions with https://iota.stackexchange.com/tags/legacy-protocol/info and I'll probably do a search for them regularly to add the post notice. Or you can use custom flags.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the request. I am curios if [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/274323) can solve the problem that you have mentioned? A custom post notice, if I understand correctly how it works, will not stop users to post answers or comments in the legacy questions. All it does is to inform the users that those questions are legacy. What do you think?

Comment: The notice shown for historical lock ("is off-topic") sounds a bit harsh to me, a bit like those questions would not be welcome. Also, if anyone is still running a private testnet with IOTA 1.0 nodes (for whatever reason), I don't mind if they still answer or comment on the legacy questions. On the other hand, if historical lock is all we can get, we can probably arrange using it instead. Also, I don't really know if it is a good idea if tag lists like [qubic] would end up to be empty.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! We definitely can enable the post notice. I just wanted to clarify that we choose the right tool for the problem :) I've sent a request to colleagues to enable the feature.

Comment: It should be live now. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Thank you! Looks great! I already assigned it to all questions currently tagged [legacy-protocol].